# tmux can't find sessions in socket

Tags: tmux

tmux appears unable to attach to my session.  I tried [unsetting TMPDIR or setting it to /tmp/](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9039256/974555), I tried [sending killall -10](https://inuits.eu/blog/tmux-still-alive-saying-no-sessions), and I tried calling with `tmux -S` like below.  In either case, it says `no sessions`:

```
$ tmux -S /tmp/tmux-35063/default attach
no sessions
```

`lsof -U` does not list any tmux processes.  I am aware that I had several sessions of `vim` open within `tmux`; I cannot find those in `ps aux`.  It seems to have vanished, but the socket is still there.

How can I check what happened to my tmux session, and to see if there is any hope of re-attaching?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the processes don't show up in `ps`, *they aren't there anymore,* and neither is your session.

The socket is just a leftover file, as Unix 'local' sockets do not automatically disappear when closed.

Comment: It must have crashed, then.